# How do I make a pot of coffee on a bbq grill?

Tags: coffee

I am going camping and love to drink coffee. How do I make a pot of coffee on a campstove bbq grill? I am a klutz. I think you can boil water in a pan once you light the fire but what do you use as a coffee pot? A thermos coffee pot?

Comment: Camping! That was the first impression when seeing your question title... ;-)

Comment: What sort of coffe do you want? Turkish coffe gets boiled in the pan and poured into the mug through a sieve.

Answer (score 7):

You have two 'convenient' options:

- Get a [**Campfire Coffee Pot**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DC5HG6), similar to what you have (almost certainly) seen in "old westerns". If you plan to do much camping, this is probably a good option. I have linked to one available at Amazon, but almost any camping supply/sporting goods store will carry something similar. (*McDonald's disclaimer: Hey, this is going to be HOT, handle with care*)

[image]

- Army Coffee, A trick I learned from an mess sergeant when I was in the service, this is a great technique for making LOTS (5-20 gallons) of coffee. Over an open fire get a large pot of water boiling, pour in loose ground coffee directly into the boiling water. Allow to boil for 5 minutes and remove (carefully) the pot from the water. Once the boiling stops wait one more minute and "whack" the side of the pot on the outside with a large metal spoon, this will cause all (ok "almost all") the grounds to sink to the bottom. Gently ladle the coffee from the pot to your cups. This may not be "Bigbucks Coffee Approved" but it will it will get you going.

Comment: I've made cowboy coffee where you do the same process but then swirl a beaten egg into it to capture and loose grounds. Apparently doesn't affect the flavor.

Comment: @GdD: http://scandinavianfood.about.com/od/beverages/r/eggcoffee.htm

Answer (score 6):

I'd look for one of the following:
Aeropress, French Press, Vietnamese Coffee Filter or a Moka Pot (goes right on the heat source) or a pourover.

With the exception of the Moka pot, they will require you to boil the water in a pot. The Moka Pot will go right on the heat source.

Or... if you're really into "roughing it". You could just make the coffee right in your pot and strain it out with your teeth. :-) (or a filter of some sort over your cup).

Note, I'd recommend if possible you find a propane stove of some sort as it's easier & more efficient to boil water on one, rather than on a bbq.

I used to carry a french press, but decided I didn't want to risk breaking it. Today, my personal choice for whenever I go camping I is an Aeropress and a Hand grinder.

Comment: If your french-press is made of glass I wouldn't take it camping.
If your moka pot has plastic you'll need to set up some kind of flat surface over the fire to keep it out of direct flame. Aeropress is my personal favorite travel option.
Also possible to use instant coffee, which I would never reccomend under normal circumstances but its just so much easier when you're camping.

Answer (score 0):

There's tons of gear for exactly this. Aeropresses are getting big for campers and backpackers. I'm personally taking one with me next time. Also, I see those french press travel mugs a lot.

Comment: One of the main benefits of the aeropress is that the water doesn't have to be boiling, in fact 175F seems to be the recommended temperature for brewing. It's much easier to get water to 175F on a campfire than to boil it.

Comment: Great to know! Boiling is a very lengthy process and for many wastes a lot of fuel from their stove which is heavy and bulky to carry.